# Istio/CORS - can faking ORIGIN trigger a request block on mesh side?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Based on https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23757 it's been quite some time now that I get no answer about it, so I realized that most likely I don't understand the internals and I need to shift the question in another diretion.

I have a case where vulnerability scan shows that we are vulnerable to custom origin domains. The expectation from the provider is to block request that don't match a predefined ORIGIN within a virtual service allowOrigin setting.
I am trying to send OPTIONS preflights or simple gets, but no matter what I do the mesh always returns **200**:

```
curl -s -H "Origin: http://fake" --verbose http://192.168.223.10:31380/productpage | grep -i "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
curl -s -H "Origin: http://testit.com" --verbose http://192.168.223.10:31380/productpage | grep -i "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
curl -s -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://testit.com" --verbose http://192.168.223.10:31380/productpage | grep -i "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
curl -s -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://fake" --verbose http://192.168.223.10:31380/productpage | grep -i "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

Is this something that controls only client blocking (browser) and if so how am I supposed to test it with curl?

I know how to reject a origin like, but it will just return not found then:

```
- uri:
    exact: /productpage
  headers:
    origin:
      regex: "*test.com"
```

Comment: Hi, can You add the `VirtualService` manifest? Also verify if the port used `31380` does not collide with any other services.

Comment: I will provide a complete vagrant that can spin the exact tests.

Comment: @Piotr Malec, github.com/angelovopsan/K8s-Cluster-1.16-Ubuntu-18.04-_rework. You can find all vs I have tested against in github.com/angelovopsan/K8s-Cluster-1.16-Ubuntu-18.04-_rework/…, the setup should run all tests by itself, but sometimes it may fail due to ressources, so the actuall curls for each file are here: github.com/angelovopsan/K8s-Cluster-1.16-Ubuntu-18.04-_rework/…. That port doesn't collide with any other service. – anVzdGFub3RoZXJodW1hbg Jul 3 at 7:48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer to this issue on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23757#issuecomment-670165587):

---

Hi everyone. Testing CORS using curl can be a bit misleading. CORS is not enforced at the server side; it will not return a 4xx error for example. Instead, headers are returned back which are used by browsers to deny/accept. [https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/cors.html?highlight=cors](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/cors.html?highlight%3Dcors&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNHe3PigScjzrJhzCHwqR_sanWb5rA) gives a good demo of this, and [https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/12/21/web-security-cors/#:~:text=CORS%20isn't%20actually%20enforced,header%20in%20all%20its%20responses](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/12/21/web-security-cors/%23:%7E:text%3DCORS%2520isn%27t%2520actually%2520enforced,header%2520in%2520all%2520its%2520responses&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNEmy6-dHMqCnVa7ZJyA28iIWqjQKw). is a good explanation.

So Istio's job here is simply to return these headers. I have added a test showing this works: [https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/26231](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/26231&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNF0tovkG_5bBxkD3wdKnLF7_h2oYw)